# Point on Line-Segment Distance Away from a Point

Tags: algorithm, math, computational-geometry

I am looking for an algorithm (or the name of the algorithm) that will find a point on a line-segment, if such a point exists, that is some given distance away from another point that not on the line-segment.

i.e., There exist, three points **A**, **B**, **C**; and possibly a fourth **D**. Where **AB** makes up a line-segment, and point **C** is another point somewhere OFF of the line-segment **AB**. Find a point **D**, if such point exists, that appears on the line-segment **AB** that is a given distance `distance` away from point **C**.

Answer (score 6):

Look here: [Circle-Line Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html)

`C` is the circles middle and `distance` is the radius.

Note that there may be two resulting points and that you have to check whether the point is actually on your line (or on the line that you would get by extending it).

Comment: This is a good boolean test, to check if there is such a point D. However, it does not look like it will tell me what the point(s) D is/are. Also, it looks like this is for an infinite line, I need a line-segment. Thanks, though for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

I spent WAY too long figuring this out and couldn't seem to find a simple answer anywhere, so I figured I'd post it here and save some people a lot of time.  Even though the original posting is old, I sure wish somebody had posted a simple answer long ago.  It would have saved me a couple days of experimenting.

```
public static Point PointFromEndOfLine(Point start, Point end, double distance)
{
    double x = end.X-start.X;   
    double y = end.Y-start.Y;
    double z = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);  //Pathagrean Theorum for Hypotenuse
    double ratio = distance / z;
    double deltaX = x * ratio;
    double deltaY = y * ratio;

    return new Point(end.X-deltaX, end.Y-deltaY);
}
```

The function above takes a startPoint (x,y) and an endPoint (x,y) and a distance (from the endpoint.  If your distance is negative, the returned point will be beyond the endPoint along the same line.  If your distance is greater than the distance between startPoint and endPoint, the return point will be before your startpoint, but still on the same line.  If your distance is a positive number and is less than the distance between startPoint and endPoint, the point returned will be on the line segment between the startPoint and endPoint at 'distance' from the endpoint.

The reason it works is 'Similar Triangles'.  Imagine a large right triangle.  Draw a strait line through the triangle parallel to the X axis and the x,y,z values of your big triangle and the smaller one created by the line you drew will be proportional to each other.

In other words: x/X == y/Y == z/Z

Hope this helps somebody out.

Comment: This doesn't look like it answers the original question. This finds a point that is `distance` away from one of the end points of a line segment, along the line defined by the two ends; but the original question was asking for a point that is `distance` away from a third point, that may or may not be on the line segment.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.